# Making my Vue instance global when using Browserify so the developer tools are available

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, gulp, browserify, vue.js

I'm starting to learn a bunch of new-to-me front end tools, specifically Vue.js, Gulp, Node, Babel, and Browserify.

I've got it all working, but I'm running into an issue where the Vue instance I'm creating for my application is not global and because of that (I'm assuming) I lose access to my browser's Vue devtools.

In my gulpfile I have a task for bundling the javascript app:

```
gulp.task('build-js', function (){
    return browserify('src/javascript/app.js')
        .transform(babelify, { presets: ['es2015'] })
        .bundle()
        .on('error', function (e){
            console.log(e.message);
            this.emit('end');
        })
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/javascript'));
});
```

And in my `app.js` file, I instantiate my Vue instance like this:

```
var Vue = require('vue');

Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        message: 'Worked!!!'
    }
});
```

And as a test the relevant html look like this in `index.html`:

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
        <input v-model='message'></input>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

The code works; I can type into my bound input object and see the result mirrored in the heading, but I don't have access to the Vue devtools:

[image: Missing dev tools in browser]

And the extension is definitely installed and enabled:

[image: vue devtools extension installed]

I've been searching around for a solution and have seen posts where people say to assign Vue to the `window` or `global` objects, but that binds the Vue library, not my particular instance.

Is there a way of making my Vue instance global? Am I misunderstanding how this should work?

Comment: A global `vue` is undefined in my Vue app, but the tools load fine. Something else is going on.

Comment: I was running into issues with it the other day. I reinstalled the dev tools and that seemed to fix it. I know for sure Vue doesn't need to be global for the dev tools to show up.

Comment: Thanks @BillCriswell and ceejayoz. Yeah, even at the global level the dev tools don't show. It must be something else. Bill, are you accessing vue via CDN or from local js file? Mine is via CDN and I'm wondering if that's causing the issue.

Comment: I'm using it through Browserify. Are you using the minified version or it from the CDN? Be sure to check out the notes here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools#notes

Comment: Ah, my bad. I'm using it via node too (I was looking at a different demo project when I wrote the earlier comment). I'm pulling it in via `require('vue');` which looks like it's not minified. Oddly enough the dev tools are showing now. I didn't do anything other than a tab refresh. I guess the tools are just finicky still.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you assign the created vue instance to window object it should work:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        message: 'Worked!!!'
    }
});

window.vue = vm
```

As for vue devtools I am not sure how they are activated for a particular vue instance, so far I've used them with vue router and they work out of the box.

Comment: Thanks. That definitely makes the vue instance available. The dev tools still aren't showing but I think that's because of a different issue. Either way, this does make the instance accessible so I'll give the check!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to follow these notes from the [documentation](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools#notes):

1. vue-devtools only works with Vue.js 1.0.0+.
2. For Vue version < 1.0.16, The devtool will only work with development (non-minified) versions of Vue, because the devtools hooks are stripped in production builds. This also includes builds produced by Webpack and Browserify in production mode. Vue >= 1.0.16 works with the devtools in all cases.
3. To make it work for pages opened via file:// protocol, you need to check "Allow access to file URLs" for this extension in Chrome's extension management panel.